# Receiving Webhook data

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json, webhooks

So I want to receive webhook data from a service called Chargify and I have zero knowledge of webhooks and I have been looking around and see no common link in the way to receive this type of data. Is it specific to the API? How does one go about receiving this data so that it can than be manipulated as one pleases?

Chargify's documentation is here if that helps you answer my question:
[Documentation](http://docs.chargify.com/webhooks)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Read it and summarize?

Comment: Essentially, is there a standard way to receive webhooks and if so, what is this way/how do i implement it?

Comment: A webhook is just terminology for a server-to-server HTTP request.  You could think of it as a regular user making a request to your site, with the difference of you're expecting what the URL and post data format will be.  If you're using WebForms, just make either an aspx or ashx.

Comment: @Matthew So, I saw that I could make an ashx (generic handler), but I guess my question now is: How do I accept the data being provided. I know with URL's I can get the querystring parameters, but how is this done with webhooks?

Comment: You configure chargify with the URL of where your generic handler resides.  Chargify then issues an HTTP request to that URL, giving you the data in that request.